# am I using php and html best practice correctly

Tags: php

I would just like someone to look at my code and see if I am using the php and html together properly.

This is what I have been doing, wrapping the HTML in PHP and "echoing" it out

```
   <?php
        // form for registration for both individual and business
        if (!isset($formAction) && !isset($reaction)){
            echo "
            <div id='regLeft'>
                <h3 class='location'>1 Sign up your business</h3>
                    <div class='login'>
                    <form method='POST' name='business' onsubmit='return checkBusForm(this);'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='action' value='business'>
                        <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Business Name: </div><input  size='50' type='text' name='busName' class='input' id='theFieldID'>
                        <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Street Address: </div><input  size='50' type='text' name='busStreet' class='input' id='theFieldID'>
                        <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Zip Code: </div><input  size='50' type='text' name='busZip' class='input' id='theFieldID'>
                        <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Email Address: </div><input  size='50' type='text' name='email' class='input' id='theFieldID'>
                        <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Password: <span class='requirements'>6-32 letters, numbers and _-.,@#!?</span></div><input type='password' name='pass3' id='pass3' id='userID' size='50' class='input'>         
                        <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Confirm Password: </div><input type='password' name='pass4' id='pass4' onkeyup='checkBusPass(); return false;' id='userID' size='50' class='input'>

                        <div id='agreement' align='left'>By clicking on Submit you are agreeing to our <a href='businessClaimList.html'>Terms of Service</a></div>
                        <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='business'>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>";
        } 
        else{
            echo "Do something else";
        }
    ?>
```

This is what I think I should be doing.

```
<?php if (!isset($formAction)){ ?>
    <div id='regLeft'>
        <h3 class='location'>1 Sign up your business</h3>
        <div class='login'>
            <form method='POST' name='business' onsubmit='return checkBusForm(this);'>
                <input type='hidden' name='action' value='business'>
                <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Business Name: </div><input  size='50' type='text' name='busName' class='input' id='theFieldID' value='<?php echo $busName;?>'>
                <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Street Address: </div><input  size='50' type='text' name='busStreet' class='input' id='theFieldID' value='<?php echo $busStreet;?>'>
                <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Zip Code: </div><input  size='50' type='text' name='busZip' class='input' id='theFieldID' value='<?php echo $busZip;?>'>
                <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Email Address: </div><input  size='50' type='text' name='email' class='input' id='theFieldID' value='<?php echo $busEmail;?>'>
                <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Password: <span class='requirements'>6-32 letters, numbers and _-.,@#!?</span></div><input type='password' name='pass3' id='pass3' id='userID' size='50' class='input' value='<?php echo $busPass3;?>'>     
                <div class='enterInfo' align='left'>Confirm Password: </div><input type='password' name='pass4' id='pass4' onkeyup='checkBusPass(); return false;' id='userID' size='50' class='input' value='<?php echo $busPpass4;?>'>

                <div id='agreement' align='left'>By clicking on Submit you are agreeing to our <a href='businessClaimList.html'>Terms of Service</a></div>
                <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='business'>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } else{ ?>
    Do something else
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Does your code work? the choices here are pretty much personal style.

Comment: both are fine, it all comes down to readability ... in which the later is better for syntax highlighting which you can see in your examples above

Comment: Does either way affect the speed of a page loading? Also I have a few forms that have around 50 different variables and the site will be having a very large amount of users updating possible at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Either are fine. I prefer option 2 because it allows the browser to cache it, and php won't have to touch it at all.

Here is a good post with a lot of good thoughts on this.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180501/which-is-better-to-include-html-inside-php-code-or-outside-it

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! That's the question I looked at and was a bit confused on partly because of how old the question is and if any thing has changed in the last 6 years.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the first example for two big reasons

1. It is unit testable
2. It is easier on a php editor with plugins. I'm thinking of editors like Sublime or PHPStorm

Additionally, there is no advantage like caching this file on disk. After all, the php file has to be interpreted and processed. What if the logic changes?

Start good code practice now that will make your life easier for years to come

Comment: What do you mean by unit testable?

Answer (score 0):

You second code example is the correct way in my opinion however either works.

The second code example allows for easier maintenance of your code, and better readability.